# How to fix 'the added layer must be an instance of class layer' while building a Sequential model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, sequential

I am trying to add layers to a Sequential model to train it with the fashion_mnist data. However, I am receiving this error repeatedly.

```
#import statements
```

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.keras import models

---

```
#Creating a sequential model
model=models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu),tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

#Compiling the model with optimizer and loss function
model.compile(optimizer='tf.train.AdamOptimizer',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
```

The error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ffa2750d675a> in <module>()
      1 #creating a sequential model
----> 2 model=models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu),tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    439         if layers:
    440             for layer in layers:
--> 441                 self.add(layer)
    442 
    443     def add(self, layer):

c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in add(self, layer)
    458             raise TypeError('The added layer must be '
    459                             'an instance of class Layer. '
--> 460                             'Found: ' + str(layer))
    461         if not self.outputs:
    462             # First layer in model: check that it is an input layer.

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Flatten object at 0x00000254C648FE48>
```

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Please show us the import statements at the top. If you used

```
from keras import models
```

then this error is expected as you are adding tf.keras layers to keras model.

Unfortunately, keras and tf.keras are not compatible.

If you change the import to:

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
```

then your code should work.

Comment: I have added the import statements in the question itself, can you please have a look!

Comment: Hmmm... this looks strange... you seem to be importing everything from `tensorflow.keras` but looking at the source file paths in the error log (e.g., python\python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py), it seems that the code is dealing with Keras. In your code, can you replace `models.Sequential(...` with `tf.keras.moels.Sequential(...` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I found the similar error in my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import Sequential, Embedding
model = Sequential(name='embedding')
model.add(Embedding(2, 2, input_length=7))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
model.predict(np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]))
```

Then I found this article about [tensorflow 2.0 and keras](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/).

In this article, the author said:

> Now that TensorFlow 2.0 is released both keras and tf.keras are in sync, 
>   implying that keras and tf.keras are still separate projects; however, 
>   developers should start using tf.keras moving forward as the keras package 
>   will only support bug fixes.

Then I changed my code and everything was okay

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
import numpy as np

model: k.Sequential = k.Sequential(name='embedding')
em: Embedding = Embedding(2, 2, input_length=7)
model.add(em)
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
model.predict(np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]))
print("model.weights: ", model.weights)
```