# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer using TF2.10.0 and python 3.10.8

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using TF 2.10.0 with python 3.10.8 and running into
`TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=<class 'keras.layers.pooling.max_pooling2d.MaxPooling2D'> of type <class 'type'>.`

I referred to this >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089489/how-to-fix-the-added-layer-must-be-an-instance-of-class-layer-while-building-a article to try and fix it but no luck

Here's my code. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
import PIL

model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPool2D,
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPool2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, name='output')
    ])
```

Please help :)

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code? Because it does not match with the error message, it clearly says keras.layers.pooling.max_pooling2d.MaxPooling2D, not the tf.keras MaxPool2D. This error happens when mixing keras and tf.keras imports.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, I'm sure this is the actual code. All I'm doing is trying to import the libraries and building the CNN model. I have not imported keras explicitly.

Comment: Ah yes, look at this line: layers.MaxPool2D, there is something missing here.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes. I got it! I missed a parentheses on the second call to MaxPool2D. THANK YOU!

Comment: Parenthesis are missing, compare it with other MaxPool2D calls in your code.

Answer (score 0):

that is correct you did not specify it is a function but interesting looking at the custom class, and favorites working with CONV functions and that is the reason for side padding algorithms.

Sample: Sides padding, working is specific or using tf.pad()

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyMaxPoolLayer( tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D ):
    def __init__( self, units ):
        super(MyMaxPoolLayer, self).__init__( units )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):

        max_pool_2d = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid')
        
        temp = tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
        temp = tf.reshape(temp, [1, 10, 10, 1])
        temp = max_pool_2d( temp )
        return temp

start = 3
limit = 33
delta = 3
sample = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 10, 1, 1, 1 ) )
layer = MyMaxPoolLayer(10)

print( layer(sample) )
```

Output: We need symmetric they call symmetries.

```
 ...
 [[ 14.819944  ]
   [ 10.318433  ]
   [ 10.318433  ]
   [  2.3505163 ]
   [-10.546914  ]
   [-11.872433  ]
   [ 13.375727  ]
   [ 13.375727  ]
   [  6.088965  ]]

  [[ 16.466604  ]
   [ 11.464926  ]
   [ 11.464926  ]
   [  2.6116848 ]
   [-11.865278  ]
   [-13.356487  ]
   [ 14.861918  ]
   [ 14.861918  ]
   [  6.7655163 ]]]], shape=(1, 9, 9, 1), dtype=float32)
```